# UIPickerView not appearing until touch occurs

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, touch, uipickerview

I'm programatically adding two custom UIPickerViews to another view (MainView). They work just fine but they are not visible until a touch event occurs in any part of the MainView. I've checked the class references for UIPickerView and UIView but haven't found anything that manages to "refresh" the view, unless I'm missing something obvious?

Here's my drawRect method in MainView.m. I've tried doing the same thing in viewDidLoad but with no success. Could the custom rotations/transforms etc have something to do with it?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { 
    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(50, -32, 30, 180);
    m_picker1 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    m_picker1.delegate = self;  
    m_picker1.tag = k_ptag1;
    m_picker1.showsSelectionIndicator =YES;  
    m_picker1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14/2);  
    rotate = CGAffineTransformScale(rotate, 0.075, 0.85);  
    [m_picker1 setTransform:rotate];  
    [self addSubview:m_picker1]; 

    pickerFrame = CGRectMake(50, 67, 30, 180);
    m_picker2 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    m_picker2.delegate = self;  
    m_picker2.tag = k_ptag2;
    m_picker2.showsSelectionIndicator =YES;  
    m_picker2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
    rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14/2);  
    rotate = CGAffineTransformScale(rotate, 0.075, 0.85);  
    [m_picker2 setTransform:rotate];  
    [self addSubview:m_picker2];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add subviews in a view's controller, not the view itself. I would suggest familiarising yourself with the MVC design pattern.

drawRect is only supposed to be used for the actual drawing of the view itself, not subviews.

Comment: Thank you, I've moved all of the appropriate stuff to a UIViewController and the pickers are now appearing correctly.